# How to access RabbitMQ cluster configured on Azure AKS to send message on queue?

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-aks

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/sender")]
public string Sender(string message, string hostName)
{
  try
    {
       Send("myQ1", message, hostName);
       return "successfully message sent to Queue";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return ex.Message;
    }                     
        
}

public static void Send(string queue, string data,string hostName)
{
   var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName };
   using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
   {
      using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
      {
         channel.QueueDeclare(queue, false, false, false, null);
         channel.BasicPublish(string.Empty, queue, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
       }
    }
}
```

I have configured RabbitMQ cluster on Azure AKS(**Hybrid cluster Win+Linux**) using helm and then deployed the above code by creating docker image using LoadBalancer Service to access the application. So, my API URL is like :

http://x.x.x.x/api/sender?message=Hi&hostname=rabbit@my-release-rabbitmq-0.my-release-rabbitmq-headless.default.svc.cluster.local

**Here I am passing hostname dynamically to this API as : rabbit@my-release-rabbitmq-0.my-release-rabbitmq-headless.default.svc.cluster.local**

I have port forwarded from 15672 to 3000 to access RabbitMQ Dashboard from my native computer like below image.

[image]

But not able to send the message to Queue.

**So, my question is what should I pass as host name in the API I have created(above code) to send message to RabbitMQ queue**

Below is my AKS cluster deployment details:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect from inside or outside the cluster?

Comment: An API I have deployed on Azure ASK and using the Loadbalancer IP I am calling that API . Now that API is responsible to push message to queue. i.e. pushing the message from inside the cluster

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code like:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName, UserName="RabbitMQ Username",Password="RabitMQ Password" };
```

Then I passed the hostname="**my-release-rabbitmq-headless**";
**This is the service name**.

Now its working as expected.